# Twython tweet based on string from tweets

Tags: twitter, twython

I would like to tweet based on when ever a phrase is tweeted. I am using twython and python 
how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I created a bot that tweeted depending on a said phrase, got banned after about 2 weeks though.

The source code for it is [here.](https://github.com/theferris/Botrack-Obama/blob/master/botrackobama.py) Take a look over it and let me know if it helps, I am happy to answer more questions about it.

Its not perfect, sometimes it leaves an orphaned tweet, but it auto follow backs and ran without issue for the second week.